# Getting an error: no match for operator[] in

Tags: c++, android-ndk, function-pointers

As stated above I'm getting a error:no match for operator[] in mHbbtSMFnPtrs[mCurrHbbtvState][hbbtvSMEvntsParam](hbbtvSMEvents, hbbtvSMEvntsParam);

```
typedef int (*HBBTVSMFnPtr)(int hbbtvSMEvent, HBBTVSMEvntParam smEvntParam );
static int HBBTVSMErrorHandler(int hbbtvSMEvent, HBBTVSMEvntParam smEvntParam);
```

Declaration:

```
static HBBTVSMFnPtr mHbbtSMFnPtrs[HBBTV_SM_STATE_MAXSTATES][HBBTV_SM_EVNT_MAXEVNTS];
static int mCurrHbbtvState = HBBTV_SM_STATE_TURNEDOFF; 
 typedef struct
 {
char* param;
int   paramLength;
}HBBTVSMEvntParam;
```

It's assignment:

```
mHbbtSMFnPtrs[loopVar1][loopVar2] = HBBTVSMErrorHandler;
```

and calling it like so:

```
int a = mHbbtSMFnPtrs[mCurrHbbtvState][hbbtvSMEvntsParam](hbbtvSMEvents, hbbtvSMEvntsParam);
```

Comment: Show us how `mHbbtSMFnPtrs` is defined.

Comment: Please show the *declaration* of `mHbbtSMFnPtrs`.

Comment: I suspect the folks might like a fuller stack trace and to see what `mHbbtSMFnPtrs` is, if possible?

Comment: From the error you get, this should be C++, no? why the C tag?

Comment: Voting "too localised" because it is, but also because I hope that typenames that long are "only relevant to a small geographic area"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the declarations of the variables, the most likely problems are:

- `mHbbtSMFnPtrs` isn't a 2-dimensional array (or similar container) of function pointers, or
- either `mCurrHbbtvState` or `hbbtvSMEvntsParam` isn't an integer or unscoped enumeration type, so can't be used as an array index.

If you don't get any errors from the assignment line, then the second is more likely.

If you could post the declarations of these, then we could see which is the case. Also, you should consider using readable names - that will make problems like this much easier to spot.

Comment: +1 My bet is on the first option.

Comment: Added the declaration for mHbbtSMFnPtrs

Comment: @harshalizee: OK, that seems to eliminate the first possibility. What are `mCurrHbbtvState` and `hbbtvSMEvntsParam`?

Comment: Added both. Anything else? Ok Fixed it myself. Sorry, that was extremely novice error I made in the header file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.